# Get file url schema

Tags: php, html, filepath

How do I show the user a previously uploaded file that is stored on the website's server (I am aware uploaded files should be stored on a different server) when I know the path? To explain; below in my code I have created a button inside an  element and I am trying to get it to display the relevant file to the user by putting the relevant url in the  element shows the user the file they need to see.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Total </title>
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="course.css"> 
       <script src="../jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="../jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>
<body>


<?php 
    if ($handle = opendir('../uploads')) 
    {
      while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) 
     {

      if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") 
      {                


          $real=realpath("../uploads/".$entry);


            echo  "<button class='files accordian'>$entry $real</button>
                     <div class='panel'>
                        <p>$real</p>";
            echo '<a href="WHAT WOULD GO IN HERE?"><button class="current-file" name="sent" value="View-Current-File"><img class="view-file-img" src="../images/magnify.png">View Current File</button></a>';
      }

    }       
 } 

 ?>  


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "I am aware uploaded files should be stored on a different server" I don't think that's the common belief unless you have a good reason to do so.

Comment: users will be able to upload their own files and I have heard that malicious code can be included in image  files . I am afraid I am new to this and paranoid about security !

Comment: true, file uploads are tricky. Most setups involve having the uploads in a public directory, with correct permissions and maybe some .htaccess and sanitizing the filenames. That said, as long as you aren't holding sensitive information or have mission critical applications on the same server I wouldn't lose too much sleep about it.

Comment: Back to the question, `realpath("../uploads/".$entry)` gives you what result, and what is the result you're hoping for?

Comment: it gives me the full url but when I try to set the <a href="$real">  to that path it produces this error  "The requested URL /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/tutorvid/uploads/Applicatgion Text.pages was not found on this server"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should be enough for you,

```
echo '<a href="../uploads/'.$entry.'">
        <button class="current-file" name="sent" value="View-Current-File">
           <img class="view-file-img" src="../images/magnify.png">View Current File
        </button>
      </a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using $real before you define it.

```
echo  "<button class='files accordian'>$entry $real</button>";
$real=realpath("../uploads/".$entry);
```

This should be the other way.

If you still have problems, do this and check the result.

```
var_dump(realpath("../uploads/".$entry));
```